# Android AsyncTask post to url with two subdomains

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

Is it possible to post data with `StringRequest` or `HttpURLConnection` to an url with two subdomains like ***xx.yyy.zzzz.com*** ?

```
HttpURLConnection connection;
    OutputStreamWriter request = null;
    URL url = null;
    String response = null;
    String parameters = "username="+data[0]+"&password="+data[1];

    try {
        url = new URL("https://xx.yyy.zzzz.com/login/login");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        request.write(parameters);
        request.flush();
        request.close();
        String line = "";
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        response = sb.toString();
        isr.close();
        reader.close();

        return response;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        FirebaseCrash.report(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "LOL NOPE";
    }
```

Comment: have you even tried?

Comment: Yes, I have tried

Comment: You mean like: www.abc.net.au - valid URL in Australia? Why would you not. Sounds like a code error to me. Show your code.

Comment: I have edited the post

Comment: Of course it is possible. Why do you ask? Why do you think it is not? Introduce your problem!

Comment: Because I get this error Message: "java.net.ProtocolException: Too many redirects: 21" and the connected API is working. I have testet it with an API-Tool.

Comment: @MarkusNowotny that errors means your URL or server is having a problem.

Comment: But the API ist working: https://api.myaccount.revocean.com/login/login/

Comment: Try add a cookie using CookieManager to your request. Read it here https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/cookie_handling_in_java_se

Comment: "I get this error Message: "java.net.ProtocolException: Too many redirects: 21"" -- the server does not like your request for some reason (e.g., you didn't URL-encode your parameters). Then, the server's error handling for this is broken, redirecting you to some URL that causes it to go into a redirection loop. Talk to the server maintainers and ask them for assistance.